# How can I create a clip to show the evolution of a network?

Tags: r, network-programming, png, igraph

Through `R` I can generate the topology of a network at each `t`, where `t = 2000`. What is generated is a `.png` file for each `t`.
Do you know a program (or a way) to use these `.png` files as "frames" to create a video of how the network evolves through time?
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147115/how-to-create-a-movie-from-5000-png-files

Here is the answer to your question. User virtualdub. Its open source

Comment: you can maybe look at the `animation` package if you want an R solution

Comment: example here http://rud.is/b/2013/09/19/animated-irl-pirate-attacks-in-r/ (and may other places). ImageMagick or ffmpeg/avconv. super straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most video editing software can do this.  Photos hop can compile them into a video and or a gif.